# Scalability when sending messages through websocket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, message

I am using private_pub gem (https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) combined with a faye server.

How will the performance vary when users chat 1on1 through this type of system (websocket)?

Are we talking 100? 1000? 10 000 active users? before it starts lagging?

I was thinking of using heroku server as deploy.

Comment: You will have to test it yourself. It is kind of difficult to guess the performance and scalability of an application based on 3 description lines.

Comment: why would you need more description? I was talking about simple messaging system through websocket if it is a scalable solution for whatever website that handles a lot of users.